# PassportJS Error: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind is outstanding intermittently

Tags: active-directory, ldap, passport.js, ldapjs, koa-passport

**TLDR:**  Is there a race condition issue with [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/) or [passport-ldapauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth)?

I am using the [`koa-passport`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-passport) library with the `passport-ldapauth` strategy in a nodejs application intended to authenticate a user against AD (Active Directory).  Wow, that was a mouthful.

Here is the error I am getting back from `passport.authenticate` which I'm assuming is coming back from LDAP:

`BusyError: 00002024: LdapErr: DSID-0C060810, comment: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind is outstanding.`

**The problem here is obvious, there is an outstanding bind, and it must be closed before I can make another bind to authenticate the next user.**  The solution however is not, it may either lie with LDAP or it may lie with passportjs.  I'm here in hopes to find a solution for the latter. (Going to explore config options for LDAP while waiting for a response on this one *#multiprocessing*)

Here is my code:

```
import passport from 'koa-passport';
import LdapStrategy from 'passport-ldapauth';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
const ldapCert = readFileSync(process.env.LDAP_CERT, 'utf8');

const ldapConfig = {
  server: {
    url: process.env.LDAP_URL,
    bindDN: process.env.LDAP_BINDDN,
    bindCredentials: process.env.LDAP_PASSWORD,
    searchBase: process.env.LDAP_SEARCH_BASE,
    searchFilter: process.env.LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER,
    searchAttributes: ['sAMAccountName'],
    tlsOptions: {
      ca: [ldapCert]
    }
  }
};

module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  passport.initialize();
  passport.use(new LdapStrategy(ldapConfig));
  await passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }, async (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Invalid Authentication Error');
      ctx.throw('INVALID_AUTHENTICATION');
    } else if (!user) {
      console.log('Invalid username or password Error');
      ctx.throw('INVALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD');
    } else {
      await next(); // continue to authorization flow
    }
  })(ctx, next);
```

Before we get started, know that all the `ldapConfigs` remain the same throughout the life of the application, so that means I am using the **same BINDDN and PASSWORD** for every lookup.

So as stated in the title, this error happens intermittently.  So the code itself works in general, and I'm able to authenticate users about 95% of the time, and if it ever throws the `INVALID_AUTHENTICATION` error when the password was correct, that is when I'm getting the the `BusyError` in the logs.

This problem is more prominent and easier to reproduce when I type in a bogus username/password, ideally I should be prompted with the `INVALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD` error, which I am about 75% of the time.  The other 25% I get `INVALID_AUTHENTICATION`.

I've even tried to reproduce it using `ldapsearch` command tool, paired with `tmux`. I ran a call in ~20 panes simultaneously using the same binddn and they all came back just fine (should I try to run it with more? 100? 1000?).  This is what led me to believe the issues was not with LDAP or AD, but more so passportjs.

I concluded with maybe there's a race condition issue with passportJS, but I couldn't find any literature on the interwebs.  Has anyone ever encountered something like this?  I believe that maybe the bind isn't closing because sometimes `passport.authenticate` might return before the callback is called? Is that even possible? Does it have something to do with how I coded it with async/await?

My fallback might be to ditch passportjs entirely and just try with ldapjs.  Any thoughts, comments, suggestions, discussions will be appreciated

Here is the full stack trace if needed:

```
BusyError: 00002024: LdapErr: DSID-0C060810, comment: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind is outstanding., data 0, v3839
    at messageCallback (/app/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1419:45)
    at Parser.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1089:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/parser.js:111:8)
    at TLSSocket.onData (/app/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1076:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
InternalServerError: INVALID_AUTHENTICATION
    at Object.throw (/app/node_modules/koa/lib/context.js:97:11)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?